# How to get the value of select tag with certain class and data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id='participant-detail'>
      <select class="form-control quantity" data-short-name="8"> 
      </select>

      <select class="form-control quantity" data-short-name="6"> 
      </select>
</div>
```

In these given example, how am I supposed to get the value of the first select tag with the data-short-name of '8'?

I tried

```
$('#participant-detail .quantity').find("select[data-short-name='8']").val()
```

the '#participant-detail' is the id of the container(div) of those 2 **select** tags.

How to find or navigate to the specific tag and get its value?

Giving it an id is not advisable because those **select** tags were created from some conditions.

Comment: Simplify by combining the first selector with the second? Loop over the selected elements?

Comment: `find()` looks at the children of an element, so you don't need it here. Just add the attribute selector to the end of the class: `$('#participant-detail .quantity[data-short-name='8']").val()`

Comment: `$('#participant-detail .quantity')` this is already the `select`

Comment: what about `:nth-child()` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find()` tries to find the select element inside `$('#participant-detail .quantity')` which itself is the element. Thus `find()` fails to target the element.

You do not need to use `find()`, you can specify the *attribute selector* as part of the main selector:

```js
var val = $('#participant-detail select.quantity[data-short-name=8]').val();
console.log(val);
var val2 = $('#participant-detail select.quantity[data-short-name=6]').val();
console.log(val2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='participant-detail'>
    <select class="form-control quantity" data-short-name="8"> 
      <option value="1111">1111</option>
      <option value="2222" selected>2222</option>
    </select>

    <select class="form-control quantity" data-short-name="6">
      <option value="1111" selected>1111</option>
      <option value="2222">2222</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#participant-detail .quantity').find("select[data-short-name='8']")` does not return any element as there is no child of `#participant-detail .quantity` selector with matching criteria `select[data-short-name='8']`.

You can try following approach to get the desired result.

```js
console.log($('#participant-detail').find("select[data-short-name='8']").val());
console.log($('#participant-detail select.quantity[data-short-name="8"]').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='participant-detail'>
      <select class="form-control quantity" data-short-name="8"> 
      <option value="a">A</option>
      </select>

      <select class="form-control quantity" data-short-name="6"> 
        <option value="b">B</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This only returns the first element?

Comment: That's what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my bad. That's me not reading well.

Answer (score 0):

use `document.getElementById` to select the `div` then `querySelector` to select the first child

```js
let elem = document.getElementById('participant-detail').querySelector('select[data-short-name="8"]');
console.log(elem)
```

```html
<div id='participant-detail'>
  <select class="form-control quantity" data-short-name="8">
  </select>

  <select class="form-control quantity" data-short-name="6">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You're not using jQuery which the OP asked for.